# Firebase ref.on("value" is getting called even without a change in value - node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to observe a change in my firebase DB.

This is my structure

DB
 - Authenticate : true

I am listening to changes in Authenticate like this in my node.js app

```
var authRef = firebase.database().ref('Authentication');
      authRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.val());
              res.send(snapshot.val());
      });
```

But as soon as I call `authRef.on` , it is fetching the previous value instead of waiting for a change.

Please advice.

Comment: As Ziya says, this is expected behavior. To quote the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events): "This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the nature of firebase listeners.

When you create a value listener it will fetch the data at least once.

I would do the following to prevent this:

```
var i = 0
var authRef = firebase.database().ref('Authentication');
  authRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

          if( i != 0){
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            res.send(snapshot.val());
          }
          i++
  });
```

It will not consider the first call if you do so