# duplicate values when I'm retrieving firebase users value in html table

Tags: html, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when retrieving firebase database values the values are duplicated and I don't know why the console shows only the 4 values that I have in my database [take a look at this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZaOb.png)

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
     ref.on("value", function(data){
      $('#table').empty()
        var content = '';
         data.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
             if (childSnapshot.exists()){
                var id = childSnapshot.key;
             var childData = childSnapshot.val();
             console.log(childData);
             console.log(id);

             content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + childData.username + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + childData.phone + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
         };
         $('#table').append(content);
        });

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the expected behaviour of a firebase listener. If all you want is just to get the data and be done with it, maybe use this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {// Do your stuff here}))
```

Check out this question:
[Firebase ref.on("value" is getting called even without a change in value - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063697/firebase-ref-onvalue-is-getting-called-even-without-a-change-in-value-node)

[EDIT] It's actually because of the `$('#table').append(content)` line. Put it out of the `forEach` loop and you'll be fine

Comment: still getting duplicate values

Comment: @CloudMusic even when you use `once` ?

Comment: @CloudMusic do you acctually need to listen to changes of data or you just need to get the data at the moment of the request?

Comment: yes even with `once`, I just want to grab the values  from the database whenever I reload the page or a new child added its doesn't mater my, why the values are duplicated and how to Avoid that

Comment: found the bug! It's `$('#table').append(content);` line, you need to put it outside the `forEach`

Comment: yeah that's it thank you man some times I be looking on the wrong side

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

```
    function SelectAllData() {
    firebase.database().ref('reminders').on('value',
        function (AllRecords) {
            AllRecords.forEach(
                function (currentRecord) {
                    var task = currentRecord.val().task;
                    var  description = currentRecord.val().description;
                    var date = currentRecord.val().date;
                    AddItemsToTable(task, date, description);
                }
            );
        });
}
window.onload = SelectAllData;

//-----------------filling up the table----------------------------------//

function AddItemsToTable(task, date, description) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody1');
    var trow = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.innerHTML = task;
    td2.innerHTML = date;
    td3.innerHTML = description;
    trow.appendChild(td1);
    trow.appendChild(td2);
    trow.appendChild(td3);
    tbody.appendChild(trow);
}
```

This is what I used, I didn't use jQuery for it. and I get the same problem, where it just prints the whole table again. how would I go about fixing it.

Thank you